# Docker Compose network_mode and port_binding compatibility issue

Tags: docker, docker-compose, compatibility

My docker-compose.yml contains this:

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: mysql
    restart: always
    network_mode: "host"
    hostname: localhost
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "yes"
    volumes:
      - $HOME/data/datasql:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 3306:3306

  user-management-service:
    build: user-management-service/
    container_name: user-management-service
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - mysql
      - rabbitmq
      - eureka
    network_mode: "host"
    hostname: localhost
    ports:
      - 8089:8089
```

When I try to do docker-compose up, I get the following error:

```
"host" network_mode is incompatible with port_bindings
```

Can anyone help me with the solution?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`network_mode: host` is almost never necessary.  For straightforward servers, like the MySQL server you show or what looks like a normal HTTP application, it's enough to use normal (bridged) Docker networking and `ports:`, like you show.

If you do set up host networking, it completely disables Docker's networking stack.  You can't call to other containers using their host name, and you can't remap a container's port using `ports:` (or choose to not publish it at all).

You should delete the `network_mode:` lines you show in your `docker-compose.yml` file.  The `container_name:` and `hostname:` lines are also unnecessary, and you can delete those too (specific exception: RabbitMQ needs a fixed `hostname:`).

I feel like the two places I see host networking are endorsed are either to call back to the host machine (see [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach)), or because the application code has hard-coded `localhost` as the host name of the database or other components (in which case Docker and a non-Docker development setup fundamentally act differently, and you should configure these locations using environment variable or another mechanism).

Comment: How would you combine this with network discovery?

Answer (score 5):

**Quick solution:**

Downgrade the docker-compose version and you'll be fine. The issue is with the latest docker-compose version and `network_mode: "host"`
I faced the same issue on v1.29.2 and while everything worked smooth on v1.27.4.

Comment: I guess with the earlier version of docker-compose the PORTS were accepted in the config, but then ignored. 

I need network_mode: "host" as I have a docker service listening for udp broadcast messages from boot devices on my home network - specifically Sonos speakers being controlled in node_red.

Answer (score 1):

To access the host's http://localhost inside your docker, you need to replace:

```
network_mode: host
```

with:

```
ports:
  - 80:80
```

You can do the same with any other port.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with network_mode: 'host'.

When downgrading docker-compose from 1.29.2 to 1.25.4, it worked fine. Maybe some bug added in new versions?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to connect to a local database then, when connecting to that database, don't use "localhost" or "127.0.0.1".  Instead use "host.docker.internal" and that will allow traffic between your container to the database.

Comment: I got "Connection to host.docker.internal:5432 refused"

Answer (score -1):

Get rid of the param ports in your services containing network_mode its like doing mapping twice.

mysql:
image: mysql:latest
container_name: mysql
restart: always
network_mode: "host"
hostname: localhost
environment:
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "yes"
volumes:
- $HOME/data/datasql:/var/lib/mysql
....
....